# Gráficos HighCharts en informe .pdf con knitr y RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown

Cuando trato de incorporar gráficos highcharts a un informe .pdf creado desde RStudio con Knit to PDF se produce una visualización no esperada.

1. **(*****SOLUCIONADO este apartado***, ver el primer comentario**)** Por un lado, sin definir ninguna opción en el fragmento (chunk), unas veces el gráfico se incorpora completo y otras incompleto, como muestro a continuación, pero además, en el mismo informe, dos gráficos generados prácticamente iguales, se muestran uno completo y otro incompleto. **No sé si es posible definir un retardo en el fragmento para dar tiempo a la visualización completa del gráfico antes de su procesamiento para incorporarlo al informe, si ese es el problema.**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

2. Por otro lado, cuando he intentado definir como opción en el fragmento (chunk) `out.width="100%"`, el resultado tampoco es el esperado. Y en este caso, **¿cuál sería la utilización correcta de las opciones de knitr para el fragmento y poder incorporar el gráfico controlando su tamaño, en este caso de todo el ancho de la página?**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Para la primera cuestión, la solución es añadir desde highcharter la siguiente configuración en el código de generación  del gráfico:

```
 hc_plotOptions(
  series = list(animation=FALSE)
 ) %>%
```

Ahora nos falta la segunda cuestión, que considero que es específicamente un problema knitr. Espero que más gente de la comunidad haya podido resolver.